# Update existing Gradle Libs dependencies to marshal ZonedDateTime with Jackson 2.8.5 and DynamoDB in Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I've been tasked with converting all of our existing repositories from Joda Time to Java 8 time and I've hit quite a few snags on the way. The first involved DynamoDB not inherently supporting Java 8 so I made a custom converter for ZonedDateTime with some help from the web. Results here:

```
static public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final ZonedDateTime time) {
        return time.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime unconvert(final String stringValue) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(stringValue);
    }
}
```

So that takes care of marshaling from ZonedDateTime to String and back for DynamoDB. But my last problem now is with marshaling from ZonedDateTime to String for Spring / Jackson dependency injection (I believe. Still pretty new to all this stuff).

Now according to Stackoverflow in order to do that I need `jackson-datatype-jsr310` which is [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310). But at that page it says all I need to be able to marshal ZonedDateTime is `Jackson 2.8.5`

Now in `libs.gradle` I can see that we're using Jackson 2.5.0 `jackson: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0',` so that makes sense just need to update it right?

So I update the `libs.gradle` to now say `jackson: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5',` and I've added `libs.jackson` to the `build.gradle` file's compile section: `compile(libs.jackson)`

But I still receive `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.ZonedDateTime: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)` when building.

I've also tried adding jackson core and jackson databind to the `ext.libs` definition:

```
    jacksonCore: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5',
    jacksonBind: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5',
```

and the `build.gradle`:

```
    libs.jacksonCore,
    libs.jacksonBind
```

Still no dice. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: assuming you are using jersey and jackson. Either annotate constructor with "@JsonCreate" and "@JsonProperty" for fields or implement default constructor with getters and setters.

Comment: @RamandeepNanda There should be no annotations required. The updated version of Jackson should natively support java 8 elements such as the new ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime. It's built in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/ZonedDateTimeSerializer.java here for instance.

Comment: When you updated the libraries did you update annotations imports to com.fasterxml ? If you are using gradle can you run gradle app dependencies to see the tree.

Comment: The answer was right in front of me but I confused how the libraries worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's my

`build.gradle`:

```
compile(
    libs.jacksonCore,
    libs.jacksonBind,
    libs.jacksonData
)
```

And `libs.gradle`:

```
    jacksonCore: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8',
    jacksonBind: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8',
    jacksonData: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.8',
```

I thought `jackson-datetype-jsr310` was pre-built into `jackson-core` or `jackson-databind` but apparently it isn't.